# Connecting to database to retrieve and parse JSON data?

Tags: php, json, database, api

I am trying to making a very basic html page from one of my professor's databases he has. My problem is I do not know how to get the data from the database and parse it correctly. For example, here is what I have so far. I just want to print the name of some satellites.

```
<html>
<head><title>Testing</title></head>
<body>
 <p>This is above the php.</p>
 <?php
  $json = file_get_contents("https://db.satnogs.org/api/satellites/
  ?format=json");
  $data = json_decode($json);
  echo $data->{"name"};
 ?>
 <p>This is under the php. </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this gives me a webpage that simply says:

```
This is above the php.

This is under the php.
```

With the data that should be between the two lines missing. I don't get an error, either. I know there are a lot of resources to answer this question but I've looked all over stack overflow and other webpages and can't find an answer that helps me understand the problem or solve it. Also, I'm not quite sure if I should even be using php. Any suggestion to solve the problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked before if your url returns content as you expect? maybe it return other data, like - i.e. - '{"detail":"Not found."}

Comment: quick tip, when copying and pasting the link, since there is a new line, it adds "%20/" in front of "?format=json", make sure you get rid of it to view the data correctly

Comment: also in your code there are newline. have you verified the content of `$json`? BTW, returned data is an array, so `$data->name` doesn't work. Follow @mmoreram answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, if you visit the website https://db.satnogs.org/api/satellites/?format=json, the format is json but there's no name there.

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

In that scenario you could do...

```
echo $data->detail;
```

You can decode the json using arrays as well, and is more comprehensible to be parsed.

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $data['detail'];
```

#### Update:

In fact, the url has data but only if is clean.

In that case, the result is an array of arrays :)

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($data as $item) {
    echo $item['name'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: it has data, for some reason if you copy and paste the link it adds "%20/" before the "?format=json" because there is a new line in the above code.

Comment: to use the decoded data as an array it should be `$data=json_decode( $json, true );`

Comment: Thank you all very much!